# How can i declare variable like php in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

PHP :

```
if(($a = $toto) == 'test') echo $a;
```

VB.net

```
Dim a as string = toto
if a.equals("test") then console.writeline(a)
```

I like the "one line" code design, so, is it possible to do that in vb.net ?

Comment: Is 'toto' another variable and you want to see if both 'a' and 'toto' equal "test"?

Comment: php allows you to declare and initialize a variable (here `$a`) inside the body of if block, and the variable continues to exist after the block ends. vb doesn't. vb also does not allow you to declare variable in the conditional. in vb it is invalid to say: `If (Dim a = toto) Then doSomething()`. No shortcuts here.

Comment: @Alexander : yes, toto is another variable.

Comment: @inquisitive, [code]If (Dim a = toto) Then doSomething()[/code] is exactly what i wanna do. Too bad it's impossible.

Answer (score 2):

It would be multi-liners instead like this instead

```
    Dim a As String = "test"
    Dim b As String = a

    if (b.equals("test")) then  console.writeline(b)
```

Or as Alexander suggested you could use one liner like this (which  actually not really one liner in the compiler most likely)

```
    Dim a As String = "test", b As String = a

    if (b.equals("test")) then  console.writeline(b)
```

Comment: That's it then! I'd like to add this link for reading:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke6sh835(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Still two lines. I think it's not possible to do this in one line.

Comment: Yes @cyrianox it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use the following......

I haven't done it but I hope it will help u ..

```
Option Explicit Off

Public Class Form1


    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)       Handles Button1.Click
        If ((ss = "test") = "test") Then MessageBox.Show("hi")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Interesting, but i will not use Option Explicit off. Too dangerous :)